# HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available error despite tomcat running and jsp available?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp, tomcat

I am running the following tutorial:
crunchify.com/how-to-create-dynamic-web-project-using-maven-in-eclipse/

I am getting the following error:
[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZXH9.png)

I have confirmed my index.jsp is not in the WEB-INF folder:
[project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaxAJ.png)

JSP is located in webapp folder:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.crunchify</groupId>
  <artifactId>CrunchifyMavenTutorial</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>CrunchifyMavenTutorial Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>CrunchifyMavenTutorial</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

My web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

I have gone through the steps several times.  The Tomcat server is started with no console errors.  There are no problems/warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting up tomcat in eclipse and trying to run simple hello world application, you face a lot this error. You can follow below given steps:

1. Right click on project properties, and go to project facet, select web application module, then select blue colour configuration link at the downside, and select content directory to src/main/webapp.
2. Go to deployment assembly, select java build.. and add maven dependencies.
3. Check your index.jsp should be present in webapp folder by default. you should see hello world page without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this myself.

I deleted the web.xml and recreated it by right clicking on the project name in Project Explorer -> Java EE Tools -? Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub

This changed the folder structure.  The web.xml is no longer under src > webapp.  instead it is under WebContent.

I moved the index.jsp to be under WebContent (not in the WEB-INF folder).

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BArQH.png)