# How to run a spring web app without a full Tomcat install?

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, maven-tomcat-plugin, embedded-tomcat-8, embedded-tomcat-7

I just began learning Spring MVC, using [this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/14476/spring-mvc-example#spring-mvc-example).

Entire write and build (under Eclipse) went successfully and a target `.war` file is generated.

However, I need to test-run it and I do not wish to download and install Tomcat at the moment.

I have heard there is a way to run it from within Eclipse without requiring a full-fledged Tomcat installation. How do I do that?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105061/spring-boot-without-the-web-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add to your pom.xml the tomcat-plugin:

`

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/</path>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

`

2. In Eclipse, add a debug/run configuration for `Maven Build`:
   Right-click `New`, and in that new configuration's Goals enter:
    `clean install tomcat7:run`
3. Now run that configuration (right-click pom.xml > Run as > Run configuration)

Comment: Indeed, Maven magically downloaded all sorts files and started Tomcat on `http://localhost:8080` but for some reason it keeps giving 404 error similar to the problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34968472 What am I missing in configuring it properly so that all `.jsp` pages are viewable?